# Как запустить и остановить анимацию?

Tags: javascript, svg, анимация

Есть код, который бесконечно анимирует картинку

```js
const svg = document.getElementById('svg-element')
const warp = new Warp(svg)

warp.interpolate(4)
warp.transform(([ x, y ]) => [ x, y, y ])

let offset = 0
function animate()
{
    warp.transform(([ x, y, oy ]) => [ x, oy + 4 * Math.sin(x / 16 + offset), oy ])
    offset += 0.1
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}

animate()
```

```css
#svg-element {
    margin: 20px;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/warpjs@1.0.8/dist/warp.js"></script>
<svg id="svg-element" viewBox="0 0 303 251">
    <circle cx="88.784" cy="141.382" r="88.784" style="fill: #00fbd1; mix-blend-mode: multiply;"/>
    <path d="M278.078,26.195l-161.04,-26.195l-26.195,161.04l161.04,26.195l26.195,-161.04Z" style="fill: #d867ff; mix-blend-mode: multiply;"/>
    <path d="M170.608,63.772l131.392,155.722l-213.216,30.874l81.824,-186.596Z" style="fill: #fffa2a; mix-blend-mode: multiply;"/>
</svg>
```

Я хочу создать команды, которые запускают код, ставят его на паузу и обнуляют анимацию.

Примерно так:

```
const svg = document.getElementById('svg-element')
const warp = new Warp(svg)

warp.interpolate(4)
warp.transform(([ x, y ]) => [ x, y, y ])

let offset = 0
var requestId = undefined;

function start(ani) {
    if (!requestId) {
       requestId = window.requestAnimationFrame(ani);
    }
}
function pause(ani) {
    if (requestId) {
       window.cancelAnimationFrame(ani);
       requestId = undefined;
    }
}
function stop() {
  offset = 0
}

function animate(){
  warp.transform(([ x, y, oy ]) => [ x, oy + 4 * Math.sin(x / 16 + offset), oy ])
  offset += 0.1
  self.start = start(animate)
  self.pause = pause(animate)
  self.stop = stop()
}
animate.start
```

Как мне лучше это сделать, если анимаций будет несколько?
Писать для каждой свою функцию остановки, запуска и так далее, и вызывать `start_animation_1()` не имеет смысла.

Comment: Несколько одинаковых, или у каждого будет своя функция animate ?

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME у каждого будет своя функция animate. Но команды `stop(),`play()`,`pause()` одинаковы. Что то похожее я видел в three.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну нужна какая-то надстройка над `Warp`.

Проблема в том, что не получится обойтись магическими функциями, которые сами всё будут останавливать и запускать. Например, `stop` должен знать, какие именно значения ему нужно обнулить: Вместо одного offset, могут быть 2 или 3 значения. Т.е. при инициализации нужно передать дополнительный объект с начальными значениями.

В таких случаях можно попробовать сначала придумать, как было бы удобно использвать функцию, а потом думать, как её реализовать. Сделать, и больше не смотреть, что там происходит внутри. Немного повозился, пока получается такое:

```js
class Anim {

  constructor(params) {
    /* Чтобы не пытаться запоминать, какая функция - как вызывается, 
       можно изначально согласовать и объявить где-то вверху:
       """ Все полученные функции из params везде вызываются в контексте this """ */
       
    this.warp = new Warp(params.elem);

    params.init_fn.call(this, this.warp); // инициализация для warp

    this._values = params.init_values; // Хранит параметры для loop
    this._loop_fn = params.loop; // вызывается на каждом animationFrame

    /***/
    this._animating = false;
    this._save_starting_values(this._values);
  }

  start() {
    if (this._animating) return;
    this._animating = true;

    const fn = (time) => {
      // Важна именно стрелочная функция: Чтобы this внутри не терялся.
      if (!this._animating) return;
      // Если откуда-то выставят this._animating = false, оно просто не запустится.
      // Можно уже без cancelAnimation...

      this._loop_fn.call(this, this._values, time);

      requestAnimationFrame(fn);
    };

    requestAnimationFrame(fn);
  }

  pause() {
    this._animating = false;
  }

  stop() {
    this._animating = false; // Анимация уже не запустится

    this._return_starting_values(); // начальные значения возвращаются на место
    this._loop_fn.call(this, this._values, performance.now()); // перерисовать
  }

  /***/
  _save_starting_values(_values) {
    this._starting_values = {};
    Object.assign(this._starting_values, _values);
  }

  _return_starting_values() {
    Object.assign(this._values, this._starting_values);
  }
}


/*** Использование */
const animation = new Anim({
  elem: document.getElementById('svg-element'),

  init_fn: function(warp) {
    warp.interpolate(4);
    warp.transform(([x, y]) => [x, y, y]);
  },

  init_values: {
    offset: 0,
  },

  loop: function(values, time) {
    const v = values;

    this.warp.transform(([x, y, oy]) => [x, oy + 4 * Math.sin(x / 16 + v.offset), oy])
    v.offset += 0.1;
  },
});

animation.start();

/***/
(function demo_buttons() {
  const id = (e) => document.getElementById(e);

  id("start").addEventListener("click", function() {
    animation.start();
  });
  id("pause").addEventListener("click", function() {
    animation.pause();
  });
  id("stop").addEventListener("click", function() {
    animation.stop();
  });

})();
```

```css
#svg-element {
  margin: 20px;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/warpjs@1.0.8/dist/warp.js"></script>

<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="pause">Pause</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>

<hr>

<svg id="svg-element" viewBox="0 0 303 251">
    <circle cx="88.784" cy="141.382" r="88.784" style="fill: #00fbd1; mix-blend-mode: multiply;"/>
    <path d="M278.078,26.195l-161.04,-26.195l-26.195,161.04l161.04,26.195l26.195,-161.04Z" style="fill: #d867ff; mix-blend-mode: multiply;"/>
    <path d="M170.608,63.772l131.392,155.722l-213.216,30.874l81.824,-186.596Z" style="fill: #fffa2a; mix-blend-mode: multiply;"/>
</svg>
```